# Why won't data driven map center and crop each township?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, data-driven-pages, arcgis-10.7

I need to create maps in ArcGIS Desktop 10.7.1 for many townships which are:

- centered on each township
- extent cropped at the border
- fixed scaled at 1:24,000.

Fig. 1 shows what I would like. However, as I look through various townships they do not all line up nicely in the frame. Fig. 2 is too far south and the extent of Fig. 3 is too large (red marks indicate the desired extent corners). Fig. 4 and 5 show the settings that I have for the data driven pages.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need best fit option, or assign page specific scales stored in pages field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the constraints you are trying to use are mutually exclusive. You can not have a map that is fixed scale and also is cropped to the border of the townships because it appears that the townships are different sizes.  You either need to have a fixed scale (in which case you can not have the map clipped to the extent of the township), or you need to have the township fit to the extent of the map (in which case the scale will vary from map to map).

Comment: After this prompt I reframed the problem and created centroids in each township (Feature to Point, select Inside). This was used as the new index layer for the data driven page definitions and the centering issue is fixed.